# error building ffmpeg on mac high sierra 10.13 "workspace/bin/ffmpeg': No such file or directory"

Tags: bash, macos, shell, ffmpeg

Hello I am trying to create a shell script `buildffmpeg.sh` which when ran, will download and build ffmpeg, so you can automate the process of making a custom ffmpeg build where the end result is an ffmpeg and ffprobe executable.

If you run the below script on mac or linux, it's worked perfectly, but when I test on my older macos 10.13 version, I first got an error about my ffmpeg snapshot url being too old:
`FFMPEG_URL="https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/snapshot/74c4c539538e36d8df02de2484b045010d292f2c.tar.gz"`
so I updated the var so it 'should' link to ffmpeg 6.0 (the most recent version, but im not sure if my link is correct)
`FFMPEG_URL="https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/snapshot/adb4688bfb0652b2ffa5bc29e53761e27e1a3b3e.tar.gz"`

When I run my below script on my mac terminal with the command `$ ./buildffmpeg.sh` it prints out '11' and then fails with an error:

```
...
INSTALL libavutil/ffversion.h
INSTALL libavutil/libavutil.pc
~11~
/Library/Developer/CommandLineTools/usr/bin/objdump: '/Users/apple/Documents/projects/buildffmpeghighsierra/workspace/bin/ffmpeg': No such file or directory
```

With the error being `workspace/bin/ffmpeg': No such file or directory`

Is there something wrong with how my script builds ffmpeg?

```
#!/bin/bash

set -e

CWD=$(pwd)
PACKAGES="$CWD/packages"
WORKSPACE="$CWD/workspace"
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=""


mkdir -p "$PACKAGES"
mkdir -p "$WORKSPACE"
echo '~0~'
FFMPEG_TAG="$1"
FFMPEG_URL="https://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/snapshot/adb4688bfb0652b2ffa5bc29e53761e27e1a3b3e.tar.gz"
echo '~1~'
FFMPEG_ARCHIVE="$PACKAGES/ffmpeg.tar.gz"
echo '~2~'
if [ ! -f "$FFMPEG_ARCHIVE" ]; then
    echo "Downloading tag ${FFMPEG_TAG}..."
    echo "~2.1~ FFMPEG_ARCHIVE=$FFMPEG_ARCHIVE"
    echo "~2.2~ FFMPEG_URL=$FFMPEG_URL"
    curl -L -k -o "$FFMPEG_ARCHIVE" "$FFMPEG_URL"
fi
echo '~3~'
EXTRACTED_DIR="$PACKAGES/extracted"
echo '~4~'
mkdir -p "$EXTRACTED_DIR"
echo '~5~'
echo "Extracting..."
tar -xf "$FFMPEG_ARCHIVE" --strip-components=1 -C "$EXTRACTED_DIR"
echo '~6~'
cd "$EXTRACTED_DIR"
echo '~7~'
echo "Building..."
echo '~8~'
# Min electron supported version
MACOS_MIN="10.10"
echo '~9~'
./configure $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS \
    --pkgconfigdir="$WORKSPACE/lib/pkgconfig" \
    --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
    --extra-cflags="-I$WORKSPACE/include -mmacosx-version-min=${MACOS_MIN}" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L$WORKSPACE/lib -mmacosx-version-min=${MACOS_MIN}" \
    --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
        --enable-static \
        --disable-securetransport \
        --disable-debug \
        --disable-shared \
        --disable-ffplay \
        --disable-lzma \
        --disable-doc \
        --enable-version3 \
        --enable-pthreads \
        --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
        --enable-avfilter \
        --enable-filters \
        --disable-libxcb \
        --enable-gpl \
        --disable-libass \
        --enable-libmp3lame \
        --enable-libx264 
echo '~10~'
make -j 4
echo '~11~'
make install
echo '~11~'
otool -L "$WORKSPACE/bin/ffmpeg"
echo '~12~'
otool -L "$WORKSPACE/bin/ffprobe"
echo '~13~'
echo "Building done. The binaries can be found here: $WORKSPACE/bin/ffmpeg $WORKSPACE/bin/ffprobe"
echo '~14~'
mkdir ffmpeg-mac/ 
echo '~15~'
cp -r "$WORKSPACE/bin/" "$CWD/ffmpeg-mac/"
echo '~16~'
rm -rf "$PACKAGES"
echo '~17~'
rm -rf "$WORKSPACE"
echo '~18~'
exit 0
```

Answer (score 0):

fixed by updating curl command

```
#!/bin/bash

# If you get error `c compiler failed` run `sudo apt install libglfw3-dev libglew-dev`
# apt-get install build-essential
# apt-get build-dep ffmpeg

set -e

CWD=$(pwd)
PACKAGES="$CWD/packages"
WORKSPACE="$CWD/workspace"
ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS=""


mkdir -p "$PACKAGES"
mkdir -p "$WORKSPACE"

FFMPEG_TAG="$1"
FFMPEG_URL="http://git.ffmpeg.org/gitweb/ffmpeg.git/snapshot/74c4c539538e36d8df02de2484b045010d292f2c.tar.gz"

FFMPEG_ARCHIVE="$PACKAGES/ffmpeg.tar.gz"

if [ ! -f "$FFMPEG_ARCHIVE" ]; then
    echo "Downloading tag ${FFMPEG_TAG}..."
    curl -L -o "$FFMPEG_ARCHIVE" "$FFMPEG_URL"
fi

EXTRACTED_DIR="$PACKAGES/extracted"

mkdir -p "$EXTRACTED_DIR"

echo "Extracting..."
tar -xf "$FFMPEG_ARCHIVE" --strip-components=1 -C "$EXTRACTED_DIR"

cd "$EXTRACTED_DIR"

echo "Building..."

# Min electron supported version
MACOS_MIN="10.10"

./configure $ADDITIONAL_CONFIGURE_OPTIONS \
    --pkgconfigdir="$WORKSPACE/lib/pkgconfig" \
    --prefix=${WORKSPACE} \
    --pkg-config-flags="--static" \
    --extra-cflags="-I$WORKSPACE/include -mmacosx-version-min=${MACOS_MIN}" \
    --extra-ldflags="-L$WORKSPACE/lib -mmacosx-version-min=${MACOS_MIN}" \
    --extra-libs="-lpthread -lm" \
        --enable-static \
        --disable-securetransport \
        --disable-debug \
        --disable-shared \
        --disable-ffplay \
        --disable-lzma \
        --disable-doc \
        --enable-version3 \
        --enable-pthreads \
        --enable-runtime-cpudetect \
        --enable-avfilter \
        --enable-filters \
        --disable-libxcb \
        --enable-gpl \
        --disable-libass \
        --enable-libmp3lame \
        --enable-libx264 

make -j 4
make install

otool -L "$WORKSPACE/bin/ffmpeg"
otool -L "$WORKSPACE/bin/ffprobe"

echo "Building done. The binaries can be found here: $WORKSPACE/bin/ffmpeg $WORKSPACE/bin/ffprobe"

mkdir ffmpeg-mac/ 
cp -r "$WORKSPACE/bin/" "$CWD/ffmpeg-mac/"

rm -rf "$PACKAGES"
rm -rf "$WORKSPACE"

exit 0
```

Comment: Use `--fail` on your curl commands; otherwise its exit status doesn't indicate whether the server gave a 200-series response, so `set -e` won't trigger on failures.

Comment: (also, think about getting rid of `set -e` altogether and putting `|| exit` or `|| return` after each command as appropriate; `set -e` [is generally prone to unexpected/unintended/unwanted behavior](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/105#Exercises))

Comment: Also, `cwd=$PWD` is much faster than `cwd=$(pwd)`. (All-caps names are used for variables meaningful to POSIX-defined tools, whereas lowercase names are reserved for applications like your script; see https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html)

Comment: ...and btw, instead of all the `echo '~13~'`, think about using `set -x` / `bash -x yourscript` to trace execution.